# How to position the twitter widget

Tags: html, css, twitter

simple question today.  How can I position the twitter widget?  I want it centered horizontally and vertically inside a div.  Here is the code:

```
<div class="twitterborder">

<a class="twitter-timeline tw-align-center" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" data-widget-id="591646755353186304" width="150px">Tweets by @twitterapi</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

</div>

.twitterborder {
width:27.5%;
height:300px;
margin-top:3px;
margin-right:5%;
float:right;
background:#707070;
}
```

Using the css code twitter supplies doesn't seem to make an difference, as when the values are changes nothing actually changes.  I have tried embedding a style"" in the A tag and also tried adding a class.

It currently looks like this (apologies if image doesn't work, kinda new around here):
[Image should be here http://gyazo.com/b96dcc6f03ef8b42dc654ad9fd832a50](http://gyazo.com/b96dcc6f03ef8b42dc654ad9fd832a50)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on this solution: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u59aL78v/1/)

CSS:

```
.table{
    display:table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-cell{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="twitterborder">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table-cell">
<a class="twitter-timeline tw-align-center" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" data-widget-id="591646755353186304" width="150px">Tweets by @twitterapi</a>

    <script>
        ! function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
    </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To center the widget, add

```css
    text-align: center;
```

to your css.

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/u59aL78v/).

---

Or using flexboxes for both vertical and horizontal centering:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/u59aL78v/2/).

Comment: How could I vertically center it aswell?

Comment: @TobiasYeomans I've updated with an option for horizontal too.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions in this post would center my widget (maybe I have a CSS order issue... or my custom container configuration... who knows!?)

However, this CSS solution did work:

```css
.twitter-timeline-rendered {
    margin: auto;
}
```

The `.twitter-timeline-rendered` class is set on the `iframe` element Twitter's JS code inserts on your page.

Here is my HTML *source*:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
        <!--Twitter client start-->
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" data-chrome="noborders noscrollbar nofooter" href="https://twitter.com/yourTwitterAccount" data-widget-id="yourTwitterWidgetID">Tweets by @yourTwitterAccount</a>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
        <!--Twitter client end-->
    </div> <!-- /.col -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->`
```

The `text-center` class on the `col` div ensures the widget text is centered if the widget itself doesn't load/render. Also note I don't use any kind of `wrapper` class.

Here is my HTML *after loading/rendering* in Chrome:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
        <!--Twitter client start-->
        <iframe id="twitter-widget-iyourTwitterWidget" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered" allowfullscreen="true" style="position: static; visibility: visible; width: 520px; height: 370px; padding: 0px; border: none; display: block; min-width: 180px; max-width: 100%; min-height: 200px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" data-widget-id="yourTwitterWidgetID" data-user-id="yourTwitterUserID" title="Twitter Timeline"></iframe>
        <!--Twitter client end-->
    </div> <!-- /.col -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->`
```

Note the class `twitter-timeline-rendered` which takes on our `margin: auto;` from the CSS above.

Answer (score 0):

For this add
data-align="center" to the a tag